# Jenkins job DSL - Build whenever an Ivy dependency is built

Tags: jenkins, ivy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a DSL script that I'm using to create Ivy jobs. It's pretty much finished, except I cannot find how to *disable* the `Build whenever an Ivy dependency is built` from the job.

I looked everywhere in the `ivyJob` element. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to set any option that is not supported by the built-in DSL. You have to find the relevant element in the job's `config.xml` and then use a configure block to set the option. In this case the element is `ignoreUpstreamChanges` and the DSL would look like this:

```
ivyJob('example') {
  configure { project ->
    project / ignoreUpstreamChanges(true)
  }
}
```